# Python - compare 2 columns in 2 different csv/txt files and find match

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I want to get the price of a stock on its announcement date. So I need to return the row in file 2 that contains the date in file 1.

- I have two csv files with over 1000 stock prices

  - file 1 'announcement dates' contains:
  - ANNOUNCEMENT DATES;TICKER
  - 20151116;A UN EQUITY
  - 20141117;A UN EQUITY
  - 20131114;A UN EQUITY
    ...

---

- file 2 'prices' contains prices of every trading day of each stock since 2005:
- over 1mio. lines
- DATE;TICKER;PRICE
- 20151231;A UN EQUITY;41.81
- 20151230;A UN EQUITY;42.17
- 20151229;A UN EQUITY;42.36
  ...

  ```
  data_prices = "data_prices.csv"
  data_ancment = "data_static.csv"
  with open(data_ancment, 'rt') as a, open(data_prices, 'rt') as b:
  reader1 = csv.reader(a, delimiter=';')
  reader2 = csv.reader(b, delimiter=';')

  for row2 in reader2:
      for row1 in reader1:
          if row1[0] == row2[0]:
              print(row2[2])
  ```

I dont know if it is possible to do it this way since the files are huge or if numpy or pandas is a better/faster option.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly a very common task to perform on `pandas` `DataFrames`. Whether or not performance will be an easy is something you could readily test; if I understand your question correctly, you only want to merge on the dates, and the corresponding piece of `pandas` would be the following (where you should note that I changed your dates a bit to have a non-trivial overlap)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: prices = pd.read_csv('data_prices.csv', sep=';')

In [3]: ancment = pd.read_csv('data_static.csv', sep=';')

In [4]: combined = pd.merge(prices, ancment, left_on='ANNOUNCEMENT DATES', right_on='DATE')

In [5]: prices.head()
Out[5]: 
   ANNOUNCEMENT DATES       TICKER
0            20151116  A UN EQUITY
1            20141117  A UN EQUITY
2            20131114  A UN EQUITY

In [6]: ancment.head()
Out[6]: 
       DATE       TICKER  PRICE
0  20151116  A UN EQUITY  41.81
1  20151230  A UN EQUITY  42.17
2  20151229  A UN EQUITY  42.36

In [7]: combined.head()
Out[7]: 
   ANNOUNCEMENT DATES     TICKER_x      DATE     TICKER_y  PRICE
0            20151116  A UN EQUITY  20151116  A UN EQUITY  41.81
```

Merging the two frames can be done pretty much however you want to -- for instance you might want to only have a single date column, since those are set up to agree anyway. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html for the full collection of possibilities.

Comment: i think it should be: `pd.merge(prices, ancment, left_on=['TICKER','ANNOUNCEMENT DATES'], right_on=['TICKER','DATE'])` as there will be most probably data for multiple tickers in both files...

Comment: @MaxU: I would assume that as well, but given the code snippet in OP, that doesn't look like what they are going for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dictionaries` like hash.

```
prices = "prices.csv"
ancment = "ancment.csv"

with open(ancment, 'rt') as a, open(prices, 'rt') as b:
    reader1 = csv.reader(a, delimiter=';')
    reader2 = csv.reader(b, delimiter=';')

dictionary = dict()

for row2 in reader2:
    dictionary[row2[0]] = list()

for row1 in reader1:
    try:
        dictionary[row1[0]].append(row1)
    except KeyError:
        pass

for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
    print k,v
```